# got error when get value from object in json

Tags: javascript, json

check this json response is

```
 [
   {"name": "Afghanistan", ...},
   {"name": "country 2" ,...},
   {"name": "country 3" ,...},       
  ]
```

Likewise
I want only country name in array
please suggest me how can I get only country name.

```
async function fetchval(data, name) {
  var x = await fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");
  var data = await x.json();
  //  console.log(data)

  var tt = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    var xs = data[i].name;    //somtime it gives error that name is undefined.

    // console.log(xs);

    tt.push(xs)
  }
  console.log(tt);  **i can not log out side the for loop**
}

fetchval();
```

Comment: `i <= data.length` <-- `i < data.length` length is the number of elements, not the max index. Exclude it from your loop. `tt = data.map(x => x.name)` would be an one line solution

Comment: As a first step, have you verified that `data[i].name` is *always* defined? If there can be undefined value, a fix would be checking beforehand whether data[i].name is defined: `if (data[i].name) tt.push(data[i].name)`

Comment: I did not spot the issue pointed out by @Cid. In that case though, I am wondering why, according to the comment written in the code, only "*sometime* it gives error"; it should *always* generate an error at the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: @secan I suppose *sometime* is for loops after length -1

Comment: Hey @user14918121, I just came back on this question that's getting a bit old now. Could you please check my answer with the green checkmark if it worked, please? It helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It iterates through every element and returns a new value for each.

```js
const response = [{"name": "Afghanistan",},{"name": "country 2",},{"name": "country 3",}]

// For each country, return country.name
const countryNames = response.map(country => country.name)
console.log(countryNames)
```

If you don't trust the data format of the response, here's the same code, improved, to avoid generating multiple `undefined`s when `country.name` doesn't exist.

You can read more about [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) if you want to. It's basically a `.map` that is followed by a `.flat`, that deletes every empty array `[]` in the array.

```js
const response = [{"name": "Afghanistan",},{"name": "country 2",},{"name": "country 3",},{"something": "with no name"}]

// For each country, return country.name. If no name, return [], that will be then 
// removed from the array by the 'flat' of 'flatMap'
const countryNames = response.flatMap(country => country.name || [])
console.log(countryNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition in for loop is incorrect, `for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`

```
async function fetchval(data, name) {
  var x = await fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");
  var data = await x.json();
  //  console.log(data)

  var tt = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var xs = data[i].name;    //somtime it gives error that name is undefined.

    // console.log(xs);

    tt.push(xs)
  }
  console.log(tt);  **i can't log out side the for loop**
}

fetchval();
```